# Regex for split method in String class which split the text by the condition

Tags: java, regex

I've the string looking like this:

```
word1-word2-word3-\d{1,2}\w?-\d{1,2}\w?|word1-word2-\d{1,2}\w?-\d{1,2}\w?|word1-word2-word3-(\d{1,2}\w?\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}\w?)-\d{1,2}\w
```

I'd like to split this string by '|' everywhere where it doesn't precedes by '('. So result should be:

```
["word1-word2-word3-\d{1,2}\w?-\d{1,2}\w?", "word1-word2-\d{1,2}\w?-\d{1,2}\w?", "word1-word2-word3-(\d{1,2}\w?\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}\w?)-\d{1,2}\w"]
```

I've trying to use **negative lookahead** `\((?!\|)` which split the text to on '('.

**UPDATE**

So I want to achieve not splitting the "word1-word2-word3-(\d{1,2}\w?\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}\w?)-\d{1,2}\w" on '|' where that character is precedes by '('.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: can you please give example of "not preceding by (" ?

Comment: Are the `()` are always balanced ? can be there more the one level deeper nesting of `()` ?

Comment: @CodeManiac in current I haven't nested (), so yes, only one level of deepness.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "word1-word2-word3-\\d{1,2}\\w?-\\d{1,2}\\w?|word1-word2-\\d{1,2}\\w?-\\d{1,2}\\w?|word1-word2-word3-(\\d{1,2}\\w?\\d{1,2}|\\d{1,2}\\w?)-\\d{1,2}\\w";
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\\|");

        for (String a : arrOfStr)
            System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: This would also split on `|` which is inside parenthesis which OP doesn't want.

Comment: Oh, sorry I just saw the update

Comment: No worries, feel free to correct your answer or if you can't simply delete it (any reputation change - here `-2` caused by each downvote - related to it will also be rolled back after few minutes).